# checkbox on Bootstrap 3 shows up incorrectly in responsive layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been using [Bootstrap buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons) to create checkboxes with images. When I directly use the code example, the buttons don't have a checkbox. But when I put them in a responsive layout, they have a checkbox.

I've created [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/) that demonstrates this. Is there a way to have Bootstrap buttons without the checkbox itself?

Here's the code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox">
          Checkbox 1
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox">
          Checkbox 2
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox">
          Checkbox 3
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your markup is a bit off--it should be this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 1
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 2
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 3
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

See [this demo bootply](http://www.bootply.com/kefVxfnIXG)

A few mistakes to note in your code, beyond the structure:

You have this: `<div class=".col-md-4">`, the '.' should not be there in `.col-md-4`, also, the input closing tags (`</input>`) need to be removed--inputs are self-closing

Comment: I'll test out the new code shortly, thanks! And thanks for the catches on the typos, I used an online converter for haml to html, that must have messed up the class names. I've fixed the typos in case people look going forward.